# infile for PhantomJS: how to set 'undefined'

Tags: highcharts, phantomjs

Trying to set maxHeight as 'undefined' (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4kkeg043/) in the infile passed to PhantomJS. how to fill the following json:

```
infile['exporting'] = { u'chartOptions': { u'legend': { u'maxHeight': ??? } } }
```

Comment: Don't set it at all?

Comment: In case you use only exporting from command line, don't use maxHeight param in legend options and anywhere. Then it defaulty be a undefined.